# collection_radio_button automatic submit?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way where upon clicking on a `collection_radio_button` the form will  automatically submit?

This way they don't have to click the submit button it just happens automatically.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :action %>
    Or choose a featured challenge:
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :action, [['Lose 10 Pounds','Lose 10 Pounds'], ['Exercise','Exercise'], ['Quit Smoking','Quit Smoking'], ['Run a 5K','Run a 5K'], ['Meditate','Meditate'], ['Visit Rome','Visit Rome'], ['Read a Chapter','Read a Chapter'], ['Walk 10,000 Steps','Walk 10,000 Steps'], ['Study a Foreign Language','Study a Foriegn Language'], ['No T.V.','No T.V.'], ['Backpack through Europe','Backpack through Europe'], ['Journal','Journal'], ['Go Vegetarian','Go Vegetarian']], :first, :last %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you should be able to do something like   `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :action, [['Lose 10 Pounds',...], :first, :last, onclick: 'getElementById("myForm").submit()' %> `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this...

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

The attribute selector is used here, you may want to change that to a class or something more specific for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange: "this.form.submit();"`

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :action, [['Lose 10 Pounds', bla bla bla], :first, :last, onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
```

Comment: `"this.form.submit();"` didn't work, but thanks for trying